# OneNote Audio Note Size

Tags: audio, onenote

Does anyone know the maximum size/time of an audio note using OneNote app?

Is it useful for recording an interview or won't let me record more than a few minutes per note?

Answer (score 1):

Using my Lumia 920, I have recorded a 0:52:03 hrs audio note using OneNote. I do not think there is a limitation or else it would be written somewhere either in Nokia's or Microsoft's official documentations.

Bottom line, you can record a long audio note using OneNote.